# React Native Change Background Color on Press

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity, react-native-stylesheet

I created a `FlatList` in `React Native`.
The data is:

```js
const Friends = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alex Lee',
        profileImage: require("../Assets/FriendsImages/f1.png"),
        followers: '246',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Micheal Ulasi',
        profileImage: require("../Assets/FriendsImages/f2.png"),
        followers: '106',
    },
    .......
    .......
]
export default Friends
```

**FlatList Code**

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Image, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Friends from '../database/Friends'

const FriendsList = () => {
    const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('#E2E2E2');
    const handlePress = () => {
        setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor === '#E2E2E2' ? '#5669FF' : '#E2E2E2');
    };
    return (
        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 24, marginTop: 7, }}>
<FlatList
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={Friends}
  renderItem={({ item }) =>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
         <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 16 }}>
            <Image style={{...}}
             source={item.profileImage}/>
            <View>
              <Text style={{...}}>{item.name}</Text>
              <Text style={{...}}>{item.followers} Folloers</Text>
            </View>
         </View>
         <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor, height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 10, }}
          onPress={handlePress}>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',height: 20, width: 20, }}>
               <Image style={{...}} source={require("../Assets/Icons/TickIcon.png")} />
            </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>}
  />
</View>)}
export default FriendsList
```

Now,  I want to change `backgroundColor` of `TouchableOpacity` on press. In my case, When i press one it changes backgroundColor of all. But I want only that TouchableOpacity change color which pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to highlight only the selected users from your list, you need to modify your response a little.

Firstly, we will declare a new array at the top of the component.

```
let userList = [];
```

Also, we will need to use `useState()` hook to manage our updated user list.

```
const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState([]);
```

Now, we will use a `useEffect` hook through which will insert a new key `isSelected` with a boolean set to `false` to your friend's list by iterating over your main list. Once the key has been inserted we will push the value to the `userList` and then we will set this new array to our `friendList`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Friends?.forEach((val) => {
      userList?.push({ ...val, isSelected: false });
      setFriendList(userList);
    });
  }, []);
```

Here, I have updated your TouchableOpacity, now we will change the `backgroundColor` only when the `isSelected` key is set to true otherwise we'll show a default color. Also, the same logic will be applied for the visibility of the image. And on press of this view we will call `handlePress()` and pass `item.id` as argument.

```
               <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor:
                      item?.isSelected === true ? "#5669FF" : "#E2E2E2",
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => handlePress(item.id)}
                >
                  <View
                    style={{
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    {item?.isSelected === true ? (
                      <Image
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }}
                        source={require("../../images/blue_tick.png")}
                      />
                    ) : null}
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Keep in mind, this `id` will be used to update the `isSelected` key in your `friendList`.

In the `handlePress()` we will compare the parameter `id` with the array's id and if it matches we will update the `isSelected` key to `true` otherwise we will keep the object as it is. Then, we will update our `friendList`.

```
 const handlePress = (selectedID) => {
    const updatedFriendList = friendList.map((val) =>
      val.id === selectedID ? { ...val, isSelected: true } : val
    );
    setFriendList(updatedFriendList);
  };
```

Here's how it will look in action.
[image]

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/DevVibhor/b5696510e1a2580a580b8036eec5d661)